# Discord has no attribute Client

Tags: python, discord.py

Previous question that I have looked over suggests that the name of the file is 'Discord.py' however this isn't the issue this time.
Currently I am running:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
```

Which then returns

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How can I fix this? and thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a file called `discord.py`? If yes, simply change the name of it

Comment: Thank you. I accidentally made a new file with that name.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you do not name your file discord

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add the prefix in there?
and import discord commands

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "pefix")
```